# Select distinct row with max date from SQL Server table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, distinct

I need to get a set of distinct records for a table along with the max date across all the duplciates.

ex:

```
Select distinct a,b,c, Max(OrderDate) as maxDate
From ABC
Group By a,b,c
```

The issue is I get a record back for each different date.

Ex:

```
aaa, bbb, ccc, Jan 1 2009
aaa, bbb, ccc, Jan 28 2009
```

How can I limit this so I end up with only:

```
aaa, bbb, ccc Jan 28 2009
```

I assume the issue is the gorup by and distinct not getting along well.

EDIT:  Found the issue that was causing the problem, query results were as expected, not as above.

Comment: Turns out it was another issue causing the problem.  The results are not what I expected. Sorry.

Comment: Please close your question as not relevant then. Thanks

Comment: what was the fix? its good that you found solution, some more people need it as well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something is wrong either with your query or with your example results, as what you describe shouldn't be possible. How about some actual SQL and actual results?

In any event, you don't need `distinct` there since all you're selecting are your three grouped columns an an aggregate, so you'll by definition end up with all distinct rows. I've never tried this, so perhaps there is some misbehavior when using both of those. Have you tried removing the `distinct`? What caused you to put it there?

Comment: +1 for being in my opinion the most correct answer. I must admit I am very curious about Quassnoi's response on your comment. His skills are unquestionable so I currently assume we must be missing something.

Answer (score 3):

```
WITH q AS (
        SELECT  abc.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a, b, c ORDER BY orderDate DESC) AS rn
        FROM    abc
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    q
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Having an index on `(a, b, c, orderDate)` (in this order) will greatly improve this query.

Comment: This just seems like an inefficient means of accomplishing the same thing you would by grouping, unless my mind just isn't working. What am I missing here?

Comment: Assuming there is an index, this is of same efficiency as GROUP BY, but selects all columns, not only those used in a GROUP BY. The original question asked for a 'set of records'. I think I just missed what the author meant.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't realize that ranking functions operated at the same efficiency as grouping. Is that because you're using 'partition by' rather than 'order by'? I've never seen that phrase before. Good to know!

Answer (score 1):

If you run this query:

```
select 'ab' as Col1, 'bc' as col2, 'cd' as col3, getdate() as Date
into #temp
insert into #temp
values ('ab','bc','cd','1/15/09')
insert into #temp
values ('aa','bb','cc','1/1/09')
insert into #temp
values ('aa','bb','cc','1/22/09')

select col1,col2,col3,max(date)
from #temp
group by col1,col2,col3
```

You should get back:

> aa,   bb, cc, 2009-01-22 00:00:00.000
>   ab,   bc, cd, 2009-04-30 09:23:07.090

Your query will work as well so something is really wrong or you have not properly communicated the exact nature of your code.

Answer (score -1):

```sql
Select distinct a,b,c, Max(OrderDate) as maxDate
From ABC
Group By a,b,c
```

***Solution:*** Removing `DISTINCT` from the above query is the solution and returns the expected result.

Comment: This does not return the expected result, rather the exact same result. The issue originally is that `distinct` shouldn't have been used, but rather `group by` for column a,b,c